# How to wait for the async function to finish before starting the next function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I need to obtain a city in the firestore before the next function.

I want to setCity to render the city in my app.

But sometimes it gets the city, and sometimes it doesn't get the city in the querysnapshot.

There is the city in the firestore all the time.

I tried many things, but none has been successful.

So, I need help to understand with the example below, because none of the examples in the stack overflow has helped me.

```js
const getCity = async () => {
  const q = query(
    collection(db, "cities"),
    where("state", "==", "NY"),
    limit(1)
  );

  var cityTemp = "";

  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    cityTemp = doc.data().city;
  });

  return cityTemp;
};

const printCity = async () => {
  const cityTemp = await getCity();
  setCity(cityTemp);
};
```

Comment: `forEach` not support async loop. use `for(...of)` instead

Comment: `var` can give some problems, use `let` instead

Comment: @leteu But there is no asynchronous operation in the loop body.

Comment: The entire idea of async functions is to have them execute out of order. If you want functions to execute sequentially, don't use async.

Comment: The code looks fine. (the loop is needlessly complicated but that shouldn't affect your issue)

Comment: @trincot There's at most one item, see `limit(1)`. But I agree it's a bit weird, IIRC firestore also has a function to get only a single document not a collection.

Comment: Ah, yes, missed that limit.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts in all possible ways, I managed to obtain the expected result using the following code:

```
    const getCity = async (stateAux) => {

               const q = query(collection(db, "cities"),  where("state", "==", stateAux), limit(1));

               const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
               querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                       setCity(doc.data().city);
               });

    }


    const printCity = async () => {

            var stateIn = await getState();

            if(stateIn){
                console.log("if");
                getCity(stateIn)
            } else {
                console.log("else");
            }

    }
```

But I have no idea why IF holds code execution until it takes time to load stateIn.
If someone has the response, please share here.

Answer (score -1):

Firestore queries are **asynchronous**,
using `await` to fetch the data, which is the correct approach.
the issue might be that the query doesn't always return a success result,
make sure to handle errors with `try catch` block.

```
const getCity = async () => {
  const q = query(
    collection(db, "cities"),
    where("state", "==", "NY"),
    limit(1)
  )

  try {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
      const doc = querySnapshot?.docs?.[0];
      return doc.data().city
    } else {
      return
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in getting city", error);
    return;
  }
};

const printCity = async () => {
  try {
    const cityTemp = await getCity();
    setCity(cityTemp)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error setting city:", error)
    setCity("")
  }
}
```

Comment: Every time it enters ELSE, even though it has data in Firestore to return in the querySnapshot